# Cloud IDE unable to connect to heroku

Tags: heroku, c9.io

I am having a problem trying to login to heroku via Cloud 9 IDE. I recieve this error when trying to login.

```
jafar70:~/workspace (master) $ heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials.
Email: jafsalami@hotmail.co.uk
Password (typing will be hidden): 
 ▸    HTTP Error: https://api.heroku.com/login 410 Gone
 ▸    Invalid response from API.
 ▸    HTTP 410
 ▸    {email password}
 ▸    
 ▸    Are you behind a proxy?
 ▸    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli#using-an-http-proxy
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update the Heroku CLI. For that, do:

```
wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Comment: Thank you for this!